# Firefox add-ons/webextensions does not support storage.session

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

As per the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/session, Firefox does not support `storage.session`.

Why is that the case, and is Firefox planning to support it in the future? I could not find any context for this incompatibility.

And in the meantime, are there any alternatives that could fill the role played by the `storage.session` API?

Comment: You can use a persistent background page.

Comment: How would I put that into use? Knowing that the extension I am using storage.session in the chrome extension, and trying to make the extension compatible with a usage on firefox.

Comment: Naturally you would make two extensions. In FF you would use a persistent background script, no storage. When they implement this API you'll be able to unify the code.

Comment: But even with that there would be an issue as background scripts can only be non-persistent in Manifest v3 (Cf. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Background_scripts) right?

Comment: Naturally your Firefox extension will be ManifestV2 until the API is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

This is now supported in Firefox 115, see [the browser compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/session#browser_compatibility) as well as [the Bugzilla ticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1823713) (note, however, that this apperently doesn't seem to work reliably on Firefox for Android for now, see [this Bugzilla ticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1823714)).